# Is a function satisfying these premises, ae. positive or zero?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let g be defined on $[0,1]$ such that the integral between $t_0$ and $t_1$, for all $t_0 < t_1$, is positive or zero. Does g satisfy $g(x) \ge 0$ ae. ?
If not, what if we add the continuity ?

I thought about saying that if it was negative on some measure-positive set A, then take an interval within A and obtain a contradiction. But not every measure-positive set contains an interval.

Comment: You **START** the question by sayin "*It* is defined".... what is this **it**? Can you please rephrase the question? Currently, I have no idea what you are asking,

Comment: I am talking about an unkown function g.

Comment: That's not helpful. You didn't define $g$. I don't know what your premise is. I don't even know exactly what you want to prove. Your question has no heads or tails.

Comment: I have edited the question to suit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $g$ is integrable and  $\int_a^b g \ge 0$ for all $0 \le a \le b \le 1$. Then $g(x) \ge 0$ ae. $x \in [0,1]$.

Let $\phi(t) = \int_0^t g$, then the Lebesgue differentiation theorem shows that
$\phi$ is ae. differentiable with $\phi'(t) = g(t)$ ae.

Suppose $x<y$, then $\phi(y) = \phi(x)+ \int_x^y g \ge \phi(x)$, so 
$\phi$ is non decreasing, hence $\phi'(t) \ge 0$.

Hence $g(t) \ge $ ae.

Comment: But why would $\phi' (t)$ be $\geq 0$ a.e.?

Comment: @5xum: It follows from $\int_a^b g \ge 0$. See my edits.